# Trouble in paradise with jQuery Mobile $.mobile.changePage() (not chaning page)

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, event-handling

I have a simple login form. 2 php files, `mobile.login.php` and `mobile.home.php`. You log in and if the cookie is set you can now access home. The login system works but the page will not change to `mobile.home.php`, it just shows the login form again. The form is Ajax and here is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#login').live('pageinit', function() {
    $('form').live('submit', function(e){
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();

        $.post($(this).attr('action'), $(this).serialize(), function(data){
            if(data.success) {
                //$.mobile.changePage($('#home'), { transition: 'slideup'});
                $.mobile.changePage('mobile.home.php', 'slide', false, true);
                e.preventDefault();
            } else {
            alert('Login failed.');
            return false;
            }
       }, 'json');
    });
});
</script>
```

I have tried numerous things. As you can see I have 2 options to change the page in the code, one commented out. The one that is commented out, nothing happens. The active code changes the url to `mobile.home.php` but just `slides up` the login form again. Both `mobile.login.php` and `mobile.home.php` have page divs `id's`.

I can't seem to figure this out, any ideas?

Comment: Upon digging into the code it may have to do the the COOKIE, I will report back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be your problem:

```
$.mobile.changePage('mobile.home.php', 'slide', false, true);
e.preventDefault();
```

Dont use **e.preventDefault();** here, it will prevent a successful transition.

Here's a simple example: http://jsfiddle.net/WWfEq/

Comment/Uncomment **e.preventDefault();** to see a difference.

Comment: That was correct. Also, I forgot since the home page is not technically loading there were to cookies to be read. I had to use jQuery $.post to read the cookies.